# Как использовать значение переменной для имени элемента в XMLElement?

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

Нужно сделать некоторую обработку данных, а затем перевести их в XML. Использую `XMLElement` и методы, которые к нему прилагаются. Однако, я обнаружил, что если я передаю символьную переменную в функцию, а затем, передаю эту переменную в `XMLElement`, она выдаёт имя переменной, а не ее содержимое.

Пример, как это делаю:

```
create or replace function gen_elem(label1 varchar2, value1 varchar2) return XMLType is
  result_xml XMLType;
begin
  select XMLElement(label1,value1) into result_xml from dual;
  return result_xml;
end;
/
select gen_elem('myname','myvalue') from dual;

GEN_ELEM('MYNAME','MYVALUE')
------------------------------------------------
<LABEL1>myvalue</LABEL1>
```

Думаю, что `XMLElement` интерпретирует имя переменной как столбец таблицы.

Есть ли способ использовать содержимое моей переменной вместо её имени?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can't use a varchar2 variable in XMLElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526824) от участника [@fleeblewidget](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497489/fleeblewidget)</sub>

Comment: aссоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/11526824

Answer (score 3):

По умалчанию [имя элемента](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/XMLELEMENT.html#GUID-DEA75423-00EA-4034-A246-4A774ADC988E) это имя переданной колонки или переменной, а не их значение.

> XMLElement takes an element name for identifier or evaluates an element name for EVALNAME value_expr

Надо с `EVALNAME` явно указать, что нужно значение:

```
create or replace function gen_elem (label1 varchar2, value1 varchar2) return XMLType is
    result XMLType;
begin
  select XMLElement(evalname label1, value1) into result from dual;
  return result;
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
select gen_elem ('myname','myvalue') result from dual;

RESULT
--------------------------
<myname>myvalue</myname>
```